# Having problems with node.js when trying to integrate firebase into my project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

(I'm a noob, so pardon me if I say some nonsense)
So, I was creating a JS project on VS code, and decided to use `firebase` to make a functioning user registration, login and database using `firebase/firestore`. 
[This is my project](https://github.com/Irismiranda/My-Library/tree/main) btw...
So basically my question is: what am I doing wrong here? Even gpt chat is having a hard time helping me lol

I tried using npm and esbuild as [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?hl=pt-br&platform=web) suggests. I used a separate file for `firebase configuration` and another one for the rest of the functions for the app, but also tried to do all the register process and firebase config in a single file. 
Since I was using the `DOM` before, it doesn't work anymore as the whole thing turned into a node apparently. So I get now the error `.document is not defined`.
I also tried using `namespace` instead of `modules`, but apparently I'm doing something wrong, cause I get another error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Right now I'm having both errors, even though I was able to create a new user through the following code (although the `DOM` is not working anywhere in my app anymore, so I can't get any of the input values to create a real account).

```
try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    first: "Alan",
    middle: "Mathison",
    last: "Turing",
    born: 1912
  });

  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```